# Yarn 3 how to fix incompatible transitive dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-v3

Say I have a dependency graph like this:

```
root - d1 - d3 (v1.1)
    `- d2 - d3 (v1.2)
```

and for some reason d3 v1.1 and v1.2 are incompatible (i.e., **d1 has to use d3 v1.1**, **d2 has to use d3 v1.2**).

Is there a way in Yarn 3 to make this work?

Comment: I see your boldface text, but I assume, since you have a minor revision that the system is assuming that it's fair to replace v1.1 with v1.2  (because it should be a non-breaking change).  But since someone has made a breaking change in v1.2 without bumping the major version, that's the d3 package maintainer's error.  I believe your question is fundamentally different if you were to ask about `d1 - d3 (v1.0)` and `d2 - d3 (v2.0)` (i,e, a major version change is semantically different from a minor version change)

Comment: @Wyck You're right, v1.0 and v2.0 would be a better example